# how to print a number in a particular pattern?

Tags: php

I have a pattern of integer (0000012019).  where 2019 is current year and 000001 need to increase with every new row inserted to db like 000002, 000003, 000004, 000005 and so on.
how can i achieve this?

Comment: Have you written a code? Could you share it with us?

Comment: no i have not, i have no idea where to start @powerPixie

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all it's a string you have.
You can split the string with substr() and do the math on the first part and then convert back to string with str_pad by padding with 0's from left.

```
$str = '0000012019';
$first = substr($str, 0, 6);
$year = substr($str, -4);


$first = str_pad($first+1, 6, 0, STR_PAD_LEFT);
$new = $first . $year;
echo $new; // 0000022019
```

Comment: this is working . thank you @Andreas